# Look up value in shadowmap

Tags: opengl, glsl, shadow, texture2d

Why does the glsl-function for `sampler2DShadow` take a `vec3`, when the depth buffer texture is a `2D` texture?

```
float texture(sampler2DShadow sampler, vec3 P, [float bias]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This texture access does not return real value under the shadow map, but actually **the result of comparison** between point.z and a value in the map on location (point.x, point.y)- `0` or `1` (for nearest filtering), or value in between when linear filtering is used.

- http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Shadow_samplers
- http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object#Comparison_mode

note that `GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE​` used in [glSamplerParameter](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlSamplerParameter) or [glTexParameter](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glTexParameter) should be enabled.